# removal of all tags from URL using php functions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, xss

want to remove all unwanted / illegal characters from the url using php function to avoid XSS. How do i achieve it ?

Example :

https://test.com/abcd/contactus.php/t54xd">alert(1)rvdgz?id=1

valid url is - https://test.com/abcd/contactus.php

Note : want to remove all tags not just specific script tag. Also the content within the tags should be removed.

Tried filter_var, strip_tags functions but was of no use. I think the only solution will be to use preg_replace / preg_replace_all function. Can anyone please provide me with the regular expression to be used to achieve the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

(this should be several comments - but posting as an answer due to length / formatting considerations)

I am *really* struggling to imagine what code would be vulnerable to an XSS attack when presented with:

```
 https://test.com/abcd/contactus.php/t54xd">alert(1)rvdgz?id=1
```

> want to remove all tags

But there are no (html) tags in the example you provided (unless they've been mangled by the editor here on SO).

The golden rule is:

- validate input
- escape output

i.e.

If you don't like the look of input, do not accept it. Do not attempt to change the data to something acceptable (unless you absolutely know you can preserve and recover both the original information and the fact of the transformation).

Always ensure that the representation of data is appropriate to where it is going at the point where it leaves your code. Writing data into Javascript, into an SQL statement, into CSS, into HTML, into a CSV file....all require different representations of data.

But you seem to be trying to apply a non-linear, non-reversible transform to input here.

Your input is [not a valid URL](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) but oddly, on my local PHP 5.3.3 installation, filter_var() does not complain about it (a `>` character is not allowed in the path). From RFC 2396:

> Although they are disallowed within the URI syntax, we include here a description of those US-ASCII characters that have been excluded and the reasons for their exclusion.[...] The angle-bracket "<" and ">" and double-quote (") characters are excluded.

The RFC describes *in detail* what a valid URL should look like. Implementing a function to apply this validation is trivial, however, **this will not prevent XSS attacks**

If the URL you have provided is a valid attack, then any solution to your problem would be too localized to discuss here, and better addressed by fixing the bugs elsewhere in your code.